# Top left and top right rounded edge

Tags: java, android, textview

I am trying to make the top left and top right round and the bottom left and bottom left square.

I have the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <stroke
        android:width="0dp"
        android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <solid android:color="#D30308" />
    <padding
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="0dp" />
    <corners
        android:radius="10dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topRightRadius="10dp" />
</shape>
```

But it makes all side round:

[image]

What do I have to modify in my code to accomplish it?

Comment: why you set `android:radius="10dp"`? i think you should change it to `android:radius="0dp"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove `android:radius="10dp"` to get this:

```
<corners
        android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topRightRadius="10dp" />
```

I think that `android:radius` is a parameter for all corners.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12793006/how-to-round-the-corner-of-one-side-of-textview-in-android answered my question. I had to run it before it took affect :)